# how to display image from upload directory on show.php page

Tags: html

Images are stored in the folder name upload in my website directory.
can anybody tell me how will i display it in another page name show.php

This question might be very basic level but I am very new to php.

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP - it's just basic HTML. :-)

Comment: Perhaps OP is asking how to read a directory of images and output them all to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Scan the directory for all image names and then output the image tag with the src set to the path for the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/upload/name-of-image-file-here" />
```

assuming the upload directory is web-accessible and whatnot. If not, then you'll need to do a script to handle the output of the image, of which there are plenty of sample questions/answers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use PHP to scan the directory with the images in it and then generate HTML to show them.

You might want to look into the [Directory Iterator](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) object. You can use that to loop through the images and then generate the HTML as needed.

For getting files, you might want to use the following code (based on [this PHP Documentation sample](http://us.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isfile.php)):

```
<?php
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        //Add filetype check here and then echo the HTML
        echo $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
}
?>
```